# Design pattern using a Queue to handle Concurrency issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, concurrency, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with SQL Server. In SQL Server there is a `Job` table. The application has a page that shows information from the `Job` table and also has a `Next` button. When the user clicks the `Next` button, it saves the current job and also gets the next available job from the `Job` table.

```
// This is jQuery Ajax POST on Next button click
[HttpPost]
public asyc Task<ActionResult> Next(JobModel model)
{
    // Save Current Job
    var jobEntity = _dbContext.Jobs.Where(x=>x.JobID == model.JobID).SingleOrDefaultAsnc();   
    MapModelToEntity(model, jobEntity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Get Next Job   
    var userID = GetUserIDFromSession();
    var job  = await _dbContext.Jobs
                               .Where(x => x.UserID == null)
                               .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if(job != null)
    {
         job.UserID = userID;

         // Noticing DbUpdateConcurrencyException here 
         await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

         var jobModel = ConvertJobEntityToJobModel(job);

         return Ok(jobModel);
    }

    return Ok(false);
}
```

At any given time there will be 200+ users viewing the page and clicking on Next button. User will view the content of the job and then select/unselect one check box and then click next. So user will spend at most 5 to 10 seconds, may be less, before clicking Next button.

In addition, we also have a background job (using hangfire) that runs every minute and insert new rows into `Jobs` table depending on certain criteria.

Given this, currently I am seeing lot of `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when  assigning next job to user. And also timeouts in background Jobs.

I tried:

- When assigning next Job, I have tried adding re-try logic when there is `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.   (This reduced the number of concurrency exceptions but still not full proof)
- I have also found some solutions to handle concurrency using transaction and setting isolation level like described in the [article](https://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/). (For this I may need to move my code to stored procedure)

But instead, I was thinking implementing a queue. So when user clicks on Next, Save the current job and then put user on a Queue. Then **somehow** assign job when he is first in the queue.

But given stateless and disconnected nature of Http I am not sure, first if this is a good idea, and second if yes how would i do this. May be using jQuery Ajax constantly polling to get Next Job?

```
// jQuery ajax POST
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Save(JobModel model)
 {
   //Save current Job
 }

 //jQuery ajax start polling this method after Save is done
 [HttpGet]
 public asyc Task<ActionResult> GetNextJob()
 {
    // Get Current User From Queue
    // If he is first in the Queue then assign next job
 }
```

I was wondering there is any design pattern using a Queue to handle Concurrency issues? Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: SQL Transactions is the correct solution for this use case, IMHO. Consider a distributed web server farm - where is your concurrent queue residing? Or do you back it with some sort of a caching database? I think it's a brittle solution that will just shift your problem, not solve it.

Comment: i have not implemented Queue. I was asking if it is wise solution. I may use AWS SQS if i decide to use queue approach

Comment: How about wrapper class for dbcontext and do synchronize your db save call??

Comment: @Nauty i am not sure if get this, can you provide pseudocode?

Comment: Optimistic concurrency is your best bet here. The only issue you're having is that it's finite, likely because you're using some number of try/catch blocks, which eventually get exhausted. If you make use of a library like Polly, you can do a retry forever with exponential backoff.

Comment: For resolving concurrency issue, EF Core recommend try tach block to handle `DbUpdateConcurrencyException ` like [Resolving concurrency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency#resolving-concurrency-conflicts). If you would override the previous changes, just keep last update, I think you could ignore concurrency tokens.